# Clicking/tapping noise when accelerating talbot Express 1989

Tags: classic

My van is making a tapping/clicking noise when I'm acclerating (I've tried to record it but my phone cant pick it up over the sound of the engine). I've tried a couple of different things to fix it - changing the oil, the spark plugs, the spark plug leads, it's just had an MoT and took it to a garage to ask about it before hand and they said there was an exhaust leak from the manifold and that could be causing it, so they replaced the gaskins on the manifold for us as there were no cracks on the manifold itself. But the noise is still there (the leak is sorted) - they said that it shouldn't matter about the noise but was wondering if anyone might know what it could be?

Comment: Is the fuel tank full of year-old petrol?

Comment: Nah we move regularly, so the petrol tank is getting new petrol every couple of weeks - we changed the fuel filter a couple weeks ago too

Comment: Where is the sound coming from?

Comment: Its coming from the general engine area - its hard to get an exact region as its only doing it under load, have been told it could be that the points in the distributor need resetting

Answer (score 0):

Without a better description of the sound or an actual recording, it's difficult to say what it might be. Your best shot at getting a diagnosis is to have an experienced mechanic ride with you to hear the sound first-hand. Expect to pay for the mechanic's time.

Engine knock / detonation / preignition causes a clicking / tapping sound only when you accelerate or run the engine hard. I would describe it as similar to the sound you would get if you half-filled an empty coffee tin with aquarium gravel, then rolled the tin down an incline.

If you wait until your fuel tank is 1/4 full or less, then fill up with the highest octane fuel that you can find, you'll be in a position to see if this is the problem because the sound (and the possible damage) will be reduced or eliminated entirely.

If this is the case, you need a tune-up or perhaps a carbon cleaning.